# Linking problem when using open-mpi (using the wrappers)

Tags: mpi, linker-errors

At the linking stage, I am getting an error of the form:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mpi_allreduce", referenced from:
      _pcnaup2 in libparpack.a(pcnaup2.o)
      _pslamch in libparpack.a(pslamch.o)
      _pcgetv0 in libparpack.a(pcgetv0.o)
      _pcnaitr in libparpack.a(pcnaitr.o)
      _pscnorm2 in libparpack.a(pscnorm2.o)
  "_mpi_comm_rank", referenced from:
      _pcnaupd in libparpack.a(pcnaupd.o)
      _pcmout in libparpack.a(pcmout.o)
      _pcvout in libparpack.a(pcvout.o)
      _pivout in libparpack.a(pivout.o)
      _pcgetv0 in libparpack.a(pcgetv0.o)
      _psvout in libparpack.a(psvout.o)
```

when I am trying to link with mpifort, so that the command that is being run looks like

```
mpifort -L(lots of libraries) -l(lots of libraries) -o qlua qlua.o
```

though I am confused; because I was under the impression that using the wrapper [mpifort](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.0/man1/mpifort.1.php) should handle all the linking to the mpi library for me, so I'm not too sure what steps I should take to debug such an error. For completeness, when I run mpifort -v the output is:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/bin/gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin19 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/lib/gcc/10 --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-10 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_2' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-multilib --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/include --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk SED=/usr/bin/sed
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0_2)
```

Comment: you can `mpifort -showme ...` to get the full link command. make sure `-lmpi` is present and **after** -lparpack`.

Comment: There is something fishy here. `_mpi_allreduce` is all lower case with no zero-suffixed underscore (the default behavior for `gfortran` is to add a single underscore as a suffix. So I would guess `libparpack.a` was not built with the Fortran mangling you expect (it was possibly built with an other compiler).

Comment: `libparpack.a` was probably built with `-fno-underscoring`. You need to rebuild it without that option.